# Not able to get Pushnotification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

while i'm using push notification in iphone with local server(used php), not able to receive the notification...it shows an error like "Connection timed out (60)".....

can any one tell me clear idea for implementing the server side code (php)

Comment: Have you read the apple documentation for implementing a push server? What specific problem are you having with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this site: http://www.easyapns.com/.

They show all the steps and give to you a simple APNS server in php/mysql.

Hope it helps.